# Character encoding issue while reading api response using NIO

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio

I am reading data from API response which is of Content-Type = text/CSV and using Java's NIO package to transfer bytes between two Channels.
While the code execution is in progress, I get the below error I checked the Source API response it contains  M�

```
ERROR:  java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

Code:

```
private void downloadFile_NIO(String encoded_token) throws Exception 
{
    Path path = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
    long lines = 0;
     
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_NAME),true); 
    URL url = new URL(FILE_URL);
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + encoded_token );
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 

    ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
    FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
    fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    lines = Files.lines(path).count();
    System.out.println("lines->" + lines);
    System.out.println();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

It looks like a character encoding issue, Maybe Charset can solve this issue, but I'm not sure how and where in my existing code I can use it?

Java version - 8

Comment: Try printing or examining the value returned by `connection.getContentType()`.  The content type may contain a charset parameter.

Comment: Also, close your OutputStream *before* calling Files.lines.  In fact, you don’t need channels at all;  just use `try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) { Files.copy(stream, path); }`.

Comment: Thanks @VGR But I want to append data to same File, that's why I am using FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_NAME),true);
         ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
         fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

But With         try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {Files.copy(stream, Paths.get(FILE_NAME));} I am not able to append data to existing File it fails with error java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException

So how can I append

Comment: I rolled back your edit as that seems to ask an entirely different question, about problems with appending to an existing file. When you get a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Created new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71276100/how-to-append-batches-of-stream-data-to-one-csv-file-using-java-nio-package

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Files.lines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) uses UTF-8 when reading data. Apparently, your data is not encoded in UTF-8, but in a single-byte character encoding (e.g. ISO-8859-1, Cp1252, or something else entirely.

Find out what the correct character set is, and use `Files.lines(Path, Charset)` with the correct character set. In addition, make sure you close the file (`fileOutputStream`) **before** reading it. I recommend you use try-with-resources to ensure you close resources correctly.

Comment: Hello @Mark Rotteveel I have updated my post describing exact issue.